# Demographics of Hamas military wing

Tags: israel, palestine, 2023-israel-hamas-war, gaza, hamas

Are there any data on demographics of [Hamas military wing: *Izz ad-Din al-Qassam Brigades*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Izz_ad-Din_al-Qassam_Brigades)? More precisely:

- What is the age distribution?
- How many of fighters have served time in Israeli prisons and may speak Hebrew?
- Wealth distribution: the top Hamas leaders are known to be super-rich, but is this wealth coincidental or correlate with the advance in the ranks of Hamas?
- Educational level. Do the top leaders have opportunities to study abroad? How many of them hold degrees from the Universities in the Arab nations? Western universities? Israeli universities?

Comment: Somewhat related to framing of the Q, I guess: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/51835/are-some-of-hamas-current-and-former-leaders-billionaires

Comment: @Fizz more recent: [Where does Hamas, the second richest terror group in the world, get its $2 billion annual budget from?](https://nationalpost.com/news/world/israel-middle-east/hamas-money), probably based on [Enquête. Le budget trouble du Hamas, de l’administration de Gaza au financement de ses milices](https://www.courrierinternational.com/article/enquete-le-budget-trouble-du-hamas-de-l-administration-de-gaza-au-financement-de-ses-milices), which cites a journalist investigation by the HaAretz.

Comment: Ahh, I accepted closing my Q on that as duplicate. Now I regret that. Anyhow, even if SE rules disfavor answering old Qs (no HNQ take two), it's probably worth adding a better answer to that Q. BTW, having a 2 billion budget is not the same as stashing all that.

Comment: @Fizz [Poor Gaza, rich Hamas](https://en.globes.co.il/en/article-poor-gaza-rich-hamas-1001461154) by Globes, the Israeli equivalent of WSJ.

Comment: Voting to close - This is a good question. But please make it more focused, and break it into multiple questions if necessary. And check for duplicates too before posting as some have highlighted..